# Is EJS templating engine still under development?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, ejs

Is EJS templating engine still actively under development? I see that the last release was in 2009?

Comment: You'd have to ask the developers to be sure but [it doesn't look very promising.](https://github.com/tj/ejs)

Comment: Looks like it definitely is.  Last release was published to npm two weeks ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs